# Regex for the inclusion of one string and exclusion of a second string?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex to match these rules:

1. Contains `The contoller for path`
2. Contains a single quote (`'`), followed by any number of characters
3. The characters must **not** end in `.cs`
4. There must be a second single quote
5. Contains `was not found or does not implement IController`

**Sample Input:**

> Exception Message: The controller for path '/MyApplication/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' was not found or does not implement IController.
>
> Exception Message: The controller for path '/MyApplication/Content/bootstrap.min.css' was not found or does not implement IController.

---

I didn't work on our main application's error logging library / integration to our application, but I'm getting dozens of these log files telling me that my CSS and Javascript doesn't implement IController. Can't figure out why so I wrote something to just delete them in the mean time. It's a little bit more "rigid" than I'd like though:

```
string[] regexExpressions = {
             "(The controller for path)(\\s)'([^']*?)[.]js'(?:$|\\s)(was not found or does not implement IController.)",
             "(The controller for path)(\\s)'([^']*?)[.]css'(?:$|\\s)(was not found or does not implement IController.)"
          };

List<Regex> regexList = new List<Regex>();

foreach (string expression in regexExpressions)
    regexList.Add(new Regex(expression);

//Loop over each file in a directory
//Nested loop to iterate over my List<Regex>
//   to compare every file against every regex
//   building a list any time I find a match

//Delete files which match any one of my regex
```

(It's a little bit more sophisticated than that, but that's the important stuff)

I've just been going back and adding additional regular expressions to the `string[] regexExpressions` as I notice more and more types of unimportant error logs. However, I don't want to have to modify this tool every single time I find a new file type which throws an error I don't care about. Initially I wrote it for just *.js, then noticed *.css was throwing these too, and now today I found a few *.map files with this same error message....

So how can I change it to look for a single quote proceeded by anything but `.cs`?

I think I can probably get away with skipping the first two requirements in my list above, the important part is really just `<not a .cs file>' was not found found or does not implement IController`. I just included all the other stuff before that as I like to be as explicit as possible and avoid the risk of accidentally deleting something I might not mean to delete.

Comment: Give an example of string input.

Comment: @jdweng Updated my question to include 2 sample texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex excludes the cs files:

```
'[^']+?\.(?!cs')[^'.]+?'
```

This expression checks if the text between the single quotes contains at least one character, a dot that is not followed by `cs'` but by at least one character. It also can still match lines where the extension starts with `cs`.

The regex group (?!*something*) is called a negative lookahead.
You can read a bit more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

If you want to ensure the sentence, you can add it around like that:

```
The controller for path '[^']+\.(?!cs')[^'.]+?' was not found or does not implement IController\.
```

You can view it in action [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%5b%5e%27%5d%2b%5c.%28%3f!cs%27%29%5b%5e%27.%5d%2b%3f%27&i=Exception+Message%3a+The+controller+for+path+%27%2fMyApplication%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.10.2.min.js%27+was+not+found+or+does+not+implement+IController.%0d%0aException+Message%3a+The+controller+for+path+%27%2fMyApplication%2fContent%2fbootstrap.min.css%27+was+not+found+or+does+not+implement+IController.%0d%0aException+Message%3a+The+controller+for+path+%27%2fMyApplication%2fContent%2fClass.cs%27+was+not+found+or+does+not+implement+IController.) or [here](https://regex101.com/r/qtEymS/2).

Comment: Beautiful; works for me! Thanks. Do you know the name for that bit you changed-- `(?!cs')`? I don't know what that specific syntax is called in order to read up on it / understand it better.

Comment: @sab669 I'm glad it worked. I updated my answer concerning your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```css
            string[] inputs = {
                "The controller for path '/MyApplication/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' was not found or does not implement IController.",
                "The controller for path '/MyApplication/Content/bootstrap.min.css' was not found or does not implement IController."
            };

            string pattern = @"The controller for path '(?'path'.+)\.(?'ext'.+)'";

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

                string ext = match.Groups["ext"].Value;

                if (match.Success && match.Groups["ext"].Value != "cs")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["path"].Value + "." + match.Groups["ext"].Value);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```